Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') - after importing MUI Autocomplete component in remote microfrontend app
We have microfrontend react app using originjs/vite-plugin-federation. One of remote microfrontend use MUI component library and we try to add Autocomplete component, but we got error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
We tried many ways to solve it: we were wrapping app in StyledEngineProvider, in ThemeProvider and react context. Also we tried to set peer dependencies, tried to remove node modules and reinstall. We tried to run our apps via npx instead of yarn classic. Also we tried to upgrade from yarn 1 to yarn 4 (berry)
How can I solve this issue?

The issue is solved by adding some setting to vite.config.ts:
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        federation({
            name: "root",
            remotes: {
                postsApp: "http://localhost:5175/assets/remoteEntry.js",
            },
            shared: [
                {
                    "@mui/material": {
                        requiredVersion: "^5.15.18",
                    },
                },
                {
                    react: {
                        requiredVersion: "^18.2.0",
                    },
                },
                {
                    "react-dom": {
                        requiredVersion: "^18.2.0",
                    },
                },
            ],
        }),
});

This is simple example of config, which similar to our one. To solve problem, you need to add mui as shared dependency to remote and host microfrontend:
{
    "@mui/material": {
        requiredVersion: "^5.15.18",
    },
},

